# Build-time value injection in Dart

Tags: angular, build, dart, development-environment

I'm relatively new to Dart, but I'm trying to use Dart 2 and Angular 5 to build a fairly simple UI to communicate with an API. Two objectives I have set for myself are that

1. The API be hosted on App Engine and the UI on Firebase Hosting, as separate modules;
2. The two modules be easily usable on my local dev machine without having to modify code before a deploy.

To achieve this, I was thinking of using something like Maven's property injection or Gradle's BuildConfigField to inject the API host during build, setting `http://localhost:8080` while in development and `https://api.example.com` in production, but I couldn't find anything to this end in Dart/`build_runner`.

Is this something that's considered a good practice in Dart-Angular? If so, how can I achieve it? If not, what *would* be good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for

https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/73
if you use `webdev` or

https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1053
if you use `pub run build_runner --config=dev ...`

You can configure variables in `build.dev.yaml` with different values for a different config

From https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1053#issuecomment-368345014

> ```
> targets:
>   runny:
>     sources:
>       exclude: ["lib/builder.dart"]
>     builders:
>       sass_builder|sass_builder:
>         enabled: False
>       angular_components|scss_builder:
>         enabled: True
>       build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
>         generate_for:
>         - web/main.dart
>         options:
>           compiler: dartdevc
>           dart2js_args:
>           - --define env=dev
> ```

You can the read the value using

```
const currentEnv = String.fromEnvironment('env');
```

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/String/String.fromEnvironment.html

Comment: So _right now_, it's essentially roll-your-own, I guess. I'll keep an eye on the `webdev` issue you linked, though!